# QGIS 2.12.3-1: startup aborts after splash screen "Setting up the GUI"

Tags: qgis

Fresh install of QGIS 2.12.3-1 through OsGeo4W64 on a Win7-x64 machine:

When I try to start QGIS through the start menu, through OsGeo4w/bin/qgis.bat or the OsGeo4W Shell with the command `qgis` I get the same behaviour:

The splash screen appears and just after "Setting up GUI" it closes. No error message appears. Besides QGIS (and its automatic dependencies) no other package was installed through the OsGeo4W setup tool.

Any ideas if it is missing a dependency or how I could troubleshoot this issue with no present error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: The error was caused by the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

It turns out that just after the GUI QGIS tries to load it's own Python version and dependencies. Usually this is no issue since they pre-pend the Osgeo4W Python to the `PATH` with the start-up script.

This is obviously not done with the `PYTHONPATH`. When this points at a directory that also contains a Python executable QGIS tries to load up this one instead of the Osgeo4W one - and subsequently fails to load.

If QGIS fails to start: Be wary of your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Glad you figured this out, always good to know =)